# (Mongoose) How to search Users collection for a token that is inside an object inside the sessions array property

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, schema

So here is my User.model.js file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 128,
        trim: true
    },
    displayname: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 128,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        minlength: 8,
        maxlength: 256,
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        type: String,
        minlength: 8
    },
    sessions: [
        {
            token: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            expiresAt: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]
});

// Some irrelevant functions

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

So what i would like to do is find a User by using only the session token but it's proving a little difficult because there can be multiple objects in the session array for each User, all of which i want to search through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query like this

```
const user = await User.findOne({"sessions.token": session_token})
```

or

```
const user = await User.findOne({sessions: {$elemMatch: { token: session_token }}})
```

For more info, you can refer documentation.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/